# Showing $X$ is not separable

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,\mathcal{T})$ be a metric space and $A$ be a subspace of $X$, such that the subspace topology $\mathcal{T}_{X|A}$ is closed, non-separable and not 2nd countable. $X$, however, is separable. I am supposed to (I believe) use this to show $X$ is not 2nd countable.

The only theorem I can think of relating these concepts is, "If $X$ is separable and $A$ is open in $X$ then $A$ is separable." This doesn't help me here, however. What am I missing?

Comment: It seems that if $X$ is second countable, then so is $A$?

Comment: @John Ma Oh my gosh..... I feel like an idiot. Thank you